# Exporting 3x images in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, export, iphone

I'm currently updating my image assets to comply with Apple's iPhone 6+ @3x dimensions. I'd like to use CC's image generator to do so but unfortunately it seems that it only exports up to 2x. Does anyone know if Adobe is working on an update to fix this? Also is there an automated workaround in the meantime? I also use the program, [Slicy](http://macrabbit.com/slicy/) but they've yet to release an update.

Comment: *If* Adobe is working on *anything* -- those who know can't say, and those who say don't really know.

Comment: Just to clarify we're upscaling images from their original dimensions correct? Not upscaling from the 2x dimensions?

Comment: [Adobe generator has a github page](https://github.com/adobe-photoshop/generator-assets/issues), you might wanna do a feature request there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest Photoshop update (Photoshop CC (2014.2) allows for @3x. Go to File > Extract Assets. A panel will appear with options:

[image]

More details can be found here: http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/photoshop/features.html

Comment: Strangely, I can't find 'Extract', there's 'Generate > Image Assets' though.

Comment: From Adobe: As of the 2015 release of Photoshop CC, extract assets functionality is no longer available in the form described ...

Answer (score 1):

Try http://retinize.it/. 1x, 2x, 3x for the selected element + scaled 200% + scaled 300%. Perfect for iOS assets.

Comment: Hi Abhimanyu, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!